# Does anyone know where I can find wp7 indie game sales data?

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7

I am curious about whether to develop an xna game for the windows phone 7. It would be nice to know how the games are doing on that platform sales wise.

Something like this would be very helpful:
http://www.xboxist.com/xbox-360/games/xna-community-games-is-a-failed-experiment-010122.php

Comment: Indie Games on XBox don't get the type of trafic you'd really like to see; however, a lot of games initially targeting the Indie section with XNA ended up being Xbox Live Arcade games. Heard that on Scott Hanselman's podcast a few weeks ago, so I forget the name of the games...

Comment: @Nate: As there's only 1-3 games released per week on XBLA, and the vast majority of those are still larger/established publishers (e.g. this week, id, Konami, and Microsoft), I find it unlikely that "a lot of games" are making that jump by any measure of "lot".

Comment: Granted, it may not be "lots."

Answer (score 3):

This shows some small and grim numbers: http://blogs.techrepublic.com.com/smartphones/?p=2005

> **Conclusion**
>
> My advice still stands for the time being: do not develop
> applications for Windows Phone 7 with
> the expectation that you will make big
> bucks.

Answer (score 3):

There's a thread in the AppHub forums where people shares their trial/paid data: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/69061/421667.aspx

And yes, sales don't look very good for now... not even trials/free apps. It looks like as if not much people is paying attention to the existing apps in the market.